# Sampling using rejection method

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

I'm trying to sample 1000 numbers from a distribution with the probability density function f(x) = (1/3)x^2 , -1 < x < 2 using the rejection method. I also want to plot a histogram based on the data.

My textbook gives the following rules for using the rejection method: 
1. Find such numbers a, b, and c that 0 ≤ f(x) ≤c for a ≤ x ≤ b. The bounding box
stretches along the x-axis from a to b and along the y-axis from 0 to c. 
2. Obtain Standard Uniform random variables U and V from a random number generator
or a table of random numbers. 
3. Define X = a+(b−a)U and Y = cV. Then X has Uniform(a,b) distribution, Y is
Uniform(0, c), and the point (X, Y ) is Uniformly distributed in the bounding box.

Based on those rules I wrote the following the code, but I believe I'm really far off from a proper solution and can use some guidance

```
a=-1; b=2; c=2;

while p < 1000

    U = rand; V = rand;

    X = a+U*(b-a); Y = c*V; f = (1/3)*X^2;

    if Y<=f
       x(p)=X;
       p = p+1;
    end   

end

histogram(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly `p` is defined? Supposed to be set to 0

Wrt algorithm, it looks ok except it could be made more efficient - `f(x)` reach maximum value at `X=2`, so you could set `c` to 4/3.